Fine-Tune Tacotron2 and Waveglow Pre-train Model from Nvidia Tacotron and Waveglow Models
Does anyone knows how to fine tuned tacotron2 and waveglow model from nvida tacotron and waveglow pre-trained model?
first thing i was create my own dataset where same with format from the ljspeech dataset with also same metadata as like this:
audio1-0056|You guys want to see my tablet? of course because, you know interesting case you're curious. I wouldn't mind showing it.
audio1-0219|we send them because we love you okay what about the, what about the unchy sticker?

and also i create the waveglow dataset too like this in csv
audio1-0056, audio1-0056.pt
audio1-0219, audio1-0219.pt

i also add audio augmentation in my audio dataset too.
after i prepared the dataset, what should i do next? i was read some documentaion and guide from AI who related about this topic but i still confusing how to re-train them.
in my case i try begin code from create the set budle of tacotron dataset:
import os
import torch
import torchaudio
import torch.nn as nn
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from IPython.display import Audio

bert_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

class TacotronDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, metadata, audiofile):
    self.text_data = metadata
    self.audio_data = audiofile
    self.tokenizer = bert_tokenizer

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.text_data)

  def encode_text_into_tensor(self, text):
    inputs = self.tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")
    return inputs

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    text = self.text_data[index]
    audio, sample_rate = torchaudio.load(os.path.join(voice_dir, self.audio_data[index]))
    
    encoded_text = self.encode_text_into_tensor(text)

    return encoded_text, audio

def collate_fn(batch):
  inputs = [item[0] for item in batch]
  targets = [item[1] for item in batch]
  return inputs, targets

train_tensor= TacotronDataset(tacotron_train[0], audiofiles)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_tensor, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, collate_fn=collate_fn)

Call the tacotron2models:
tacotron2model = torch.hub.load('NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_tacotron2', model_math ='fp16')
tacotron2model = tacotron2model.to('cuda')
tacotron2model.train()

Begin to train tacotron2 models:
# define loss function
loss_funct = nn.L1Loss()

# define optimizers
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(tacotron2model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# add summary writer
loss_writer = SummaryWriter()

# Define Epoch
num_epochs = 100

# train models
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  running_loss = 0.0
  for i, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    inputs, targets = data
    inputs = [item.to('cuda') for item in inputs]
    targets = [item.to('cuda') for item in targets]
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    outputs= tacotron2model(inputs)
    loss = loss_funct(outputs, targets)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    running_loss += loss.item()
  
  epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataloader)
  loss_writer.add_scalar('Loss/train', epoch_loss, epoch)

loss_writer.close()

I try to run them but some error said this when it run on outputs= tacotron2model(inputs):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-22b395d3290f> in <cell line: 2>()
      8     optimizer.zero_grad()
      9 
---> 10     outputs= tacotron2model(inputs)
     11     loss = loss_funct(outputs, targets)
     12     loss.backward()

2 frames
~/.cache/torch/hub/NVIDIA_DeepLearningExamples_torchhub/PyTorch/SpeechSynthesis/Tacotron2/tacotron2/model.py in forward(self, inputs)
    658 
    659     def forward(self, inputs):
--> 660         inputs, input_lengths, targets, max_len, output_lengths = inputs
    661         input_lengths, output_lengths = input_lengths.data, output_lengths.data
    662 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)

So in this case, am i was made a wrong dataset format or i was really dumb to understanding how tacotron2 works? is anyone know how to solved this? i'd be glad if someone would kindly guide me how to solved this.
Thanks a lot
